# Destructuring (spread operator) works in React JSX, but not outside?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I have this piece of code in my Component constructor:

```
this.state = {
    captcha: {...ABC.XYZ}
};
```

I tried different variations like

```
const abc = ABC.XYZ;
const dummy = {...abc};
```

I always get the error.

`Unexpected token (36:18) Use --force to continue`

But, in my JSX, I have

```
<Login
    {...props}
/>
```

And this works fine.

If it's a Babel issue, shouldn't it give an error everywhere?

Comment: Destructuring an object this way is an ES7 feature so you might want to configure babel accordingly. As the answer said, it's pointless in the given example

Comment: @3Dos So why does it work in JSX within the same component? That's what I am struggling to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One works and one doesn't because they are two separate features.

```
<Login
  {...props}
/>
```

is a [JSX spread attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) whereas

```
this.state = {
  captcha: {...ABC.XYZ}
};
```

is an [ES2018 object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).

Since the first is a feature of JSX, it is transformed by Babel when it processes JSX. For the second, you'll need to explicitly enable https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/ in Babel.

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

```
this.state = {
  captcha: {...ABC.XYZ}
}
```

is absolutely equal to

```
this.state = {
  captcha: ABC.XYZ
}
```

so destructuring assignment is pointless here

Comment: I simplified it actually, since I didn't want to paste my whole code with needless information.